# What does filter use for joint_trajectory_action_controller

Tags: ros, filter, joint-trajectory-action, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am reading joint_trajectory_action_controller.cpp in robot_mechanism_controllers. Following code is about output filter setup.

```
// Output filters
output_filters_.resize(joints_.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < joints_.size(); ++i)
{
  std::string p = "output_filters/" + joints_[i]->joint_->name;
  if (node_.hasParam(p))
  {
    output_filters_[i].reset(new filters::FilterChain<double>("double"));
    if (!output_filters_[i]->configure(node_.resolveName(p)))
      output_filters_[i].reset();
  }
}
```

What does filter use for the controller?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64227/what-does-filter-use-for-joint_trajectory_action_controller/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can (optionally) setup a filter chain for individual joints. Before control commands leave the controller, they go through the filter chain for post-processing. You can register any filter that complies with the FilterChain interface. See the [filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/filters) package for more information.

By default no filters are used.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0